# Subclass doesn't inherit super class properties

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

When defining subclass, I got TypeErorr:undefined for constructor argument, which is acting as placeholder as I see. What exactly is happening and how to solve it?

```
function Class(object) {
    this.name = object.name;
}

var myClass = new Class({
    name: "ClassName"
})

console.log(myClass.name); 

function SubClass(object) {
    this.name = object.name;
}

SubClass.prototype = new Class();
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

var mySubClass = new SubClass({
    name: "SubClassName"
})
```

//TypeError: object is undefined

Comment: there is a typo: `SubClass.prototype` instead of `SubClass.protoype`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally your base class would have methods on its prototype so it would be more appropriate to use `SubClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype)`, and also call your parent constructor in the base class' constructor so that the `object.name` can be found in the parent constructor (which is the error you were getting since nothing was passed into `SubClass.prototype = new Class()`.

```
function Class(object) {
    this.name = object.name;
}

Class.prototype.sayName = function () {
    return this.name;
}

var myClass = new Class({
    name: "ClassName"
});

console.log(myClass.name); 

function SubClass(object) {
    // call parent constructor with context of the new SubClass instance
    Class.call(this, object);
}

SubClass.prototype = Object.create(Class.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

var mySubClass = new SubClass({
    name: "SubClassName"
});

console.log(mySubClass.sayName());
// > "SubClassName"
```

Here are some helpful references

- http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain
- http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html